# Cypher Query Timeout for Complex Query with Weights

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a fairly simple graph.  It only has around 100 nodes and 400 relationships.  I am trying to run a variety of cypher queries that rank the results based on the existence of certain relationships.  However, even with a small database these queries are timing out.  Can anyone identify a problem with my query that would be causing the time out?

The query below searches for a variety of patterns.  If the pattern exists, it applies a weight to the relationship.  At the end, it combines the weights and ranks the results so the node with the highest weight (most important relationships) is given priority.

```
START node=node(1) 
MATCH  (node)-[a?:REQUIRES]-(thing0)-[?:RELATED]-(stuff) 
,(node)-[b?:REQUIRES]-(thing1)-[:RELATED]-(system1)-[:COMPOSITION]-(something1)-[?:VERSION]-(stuff) 
,(node)-[c?:REQUIRES]-(thing2)-[:RELATED]-(something2)-[?:VERSION]-(stuff) 
,(node)-[d?:REQUIRES]-(thing3)-[:REQUIRES]-(project1)-[:REQUIRES]-(thing6)-[?:RELATED]-(stuff) 
,(node)-[e?:REQUIRES]-(thing4)-[:DESCRIBES]-(part)-[:DESCRIBES]-(thing5)-[?:RELATED]-(stuff) 
WITH stuff
, count(distinct a)*.15 as shareA
, count(distinct b)*.35 as shareB
, count(distinct c)*.25 as shareC
, count(distinct d)*.10 as shareD
, count(distinct e)*.15 as shareE 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) 
AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = shareA + shareB + shareC + shareD + shareE 
RETURN DISTINCT stuff 
ORDER BY stuff.weight DESC
```

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but the optional relationship matcher is often the cause of slowness. You might try splitting it up with `WITH` so you don't need to use optional relationships, if that's possible. Have you done a `profile` to see what comes back?

Comment: I'm new to Neo4j.  Can explain what you mean by "done a profile?"

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that I can rewrite the query using "WITH."  Each of the patterns I am checking are in fact optional.  I believe WITH would limit the result set to only include nodes that match all patterns.

Comment: append `profile` to the beginning of your cypher and it will give you back an execution plan. Instead of using an optional relationship try getting it to work with a *0..1 variable length pattern.

Comment: Profile shows _rows=49880, _db_hits=193791134 for PatternMatch even though there are only 118 nodes and 432 relationships.  Replacing the optional relationship with the variable length pattern had no effect (or a negative effect since it has been running for 20 minutes and has yet to return a result).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to take out the optionals, and do this in a few cypher statements inside of one BATCH request or transaction.

```
START stuff=node(*) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = 0.0;

START node=node(1) 
MATCH  (node)-[a:REQUIRES]-(thing)-[:RELATED]-(stuff) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = stuff.weight + COUNT(DISTINCT a)*.15;

START node=node(1) 
MATCH (node)-[b:REQUIRES]-(thing)-[:RELATED]-(system1)-[:COMPOSITION]-(something1)-[:VERSION]-(stuff) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = stuff.weight + COUNT(DISTINCT b)*.35

START node=node(1) 
MATCH (node)-[c:REQUIRES]-(thing2)-[:RELATED]-(something2)-[:VERSION]-(stuff) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = stuff.weight + COUNT(DISTINCT c)*.25

START node=node(1) 
MATCH (node)-[d:REQUIRES]-(thing3)-[:REQUIRES]-(project1)-[:REQUIRES]-(thing6)-[:RELATED]-(stuff) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = stuff.weight + COUNT(DISTINCT d)*.10

START node=node(1) 
MATCH (node)-[e:REQUIRES]-(thing4)-[:DESCRIBES]-(part)-[:DESCRIBES]-(thing5)-[:RELATED]-(stuff) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
SET stuff.weight = stuff.weight + COUNT(DISTINCT e)*.15

START stuff=node(*) 
WHERE has(stuff.__type__) AND stuff.__type__='full.namespace.to.stuff' 
RETURN DISTINCT stuff 
ORDER BY stuff.weight DESC
```

You could chain it all with "WITH" but I think that makes it pretty messy.

Comment: Your solution should work. However, I was planning to change the weighted approach so it doesn't save the weight to the node.  That might cause concurrency issues if multiple users are running similar queries.  I must admit that I am surprised that cypher can't handle this type of query.

Comment: Chaining these queries with "WITH" also causes a timeout.  I hesitate to separate them all out because I have dozens of these queries developed that each run in parallel.  As I mentioned above, saving the weights to the node will cause problems.  These queries ran fine with a small graph.  I really don't see the value in the graph database if it can't handle complex relationships.  A relational database would have handled this much more efficiently.

Comment: The problem is that your optional relationships blow up the query. Can you post a zipped graph.db folder somewhere so we can play with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the database.  But I was able to replicate the issue with a graph as small as 26 nodes.  For the time being, I have created more generic queries.  I appreciate everyone's help with this issue.